# Displaying Japanese Characters using DOMpdf

Tags: php, utf-8, dompdf

### Problem:

I want to generate a pdf using [DomPDF](https://github.com/dompdf) that includes Japanese text. In order to do so I know that I need a font that supports Japanese characters and to load the font into DomPDF.
I have read the [UnicodeHowTo](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo) of DomPDF and several similar questions on SO but I can not seem to get it to work. I get `?` at the place where the Japanese characters should be.

In my dompdf config I have set `def("DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED", true);` and it shows true in the admin interface as well.  The font I use (I have tried several) should support japanese characters and is loaded in DomPDF using the `load_font.php` script. I do have to note for the sake of completeness that generating the font files gives me 2 identical warnings

> Warning: strftime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone
>   settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the
>   date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
>   methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for
>   now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in ..

### Minimal (not) working example:

Relevant html stored in PHP variabe `$template`:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
<TITLE>Test voucher</TITLE>
<STYLE type="text/css">


@font-face {
      font-family: \'mgenplus\';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: url(dompdf/fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-regular.ttf) format(\'truetype\');
 }
.ft0{font: 14px;line-height: 16px;}
*{ font-family: mgenplus !important;}
</STYLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<P>ねん だい かい にほんごのうりょくしけん</P>
<!-- .... -->
```

Relevant PHP:

```
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
$template = mb_convert_encoding($template, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($template, 'UTF-8');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("test.pdf",array('Attachment'=>0));
```

If anybody has a suggestion or see if I missed something, it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I found out why it did not work and I will post it here for anybody facing the same problem.

The problem was in this piece:

```
@font-face {
      font-family: \'mgenplus\';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: url(dompdf/fonts/rounded-mgenplus-1c-regular.ttf) format(\'truetype\');
 }
.ft0{font: 14px;line-height: 16px;}
*{ font-family: mgenplus !important;}
```

I had to remove the `@font-face` block, it is not needed since you load the font from DomPDF and not from the file. The line that caused all the trouble was `.ft0{font: 14px;line-height: 16px;}` it sets the font-family to the browser default apparently and the overwrite afterwards is not taken into account by DomPDF (no support for `!important`?).

Changing the line to `.ft0{font-size: 14px;line-height: 16px;}` fixed my problem.

Comment: "asked 20 mins ago / answered 3 mins ago" next time before posting think 17 extra minutes (:

Comment: @aesede yes.. well I was working on it 8 hours already. But I guess posting the question helped me in getting an overview.

Comment: Yes, many times putting the focus on something else (even the SO syntax formatting) can make the needed mind-reset.

Comment: I dunno if it's buggy or not, might just be a specificity issue (i.e. `.ft0` is more specific than `*`). However, `!important` should override the specificity ... and it does in my testing so there might be something else going on.

Comment: The HTML/CSS you passed to dompdf didn't include the backslash in the `@font-face` declaration, did it?

Comment: Still, since a font family wasn't specified in the `.ft0` styling I think it's safe to say that's probably buggy behavior.

Comment: @BrianS no the backslash was because of inlining the html in php

Comment: @BrianS I got the same not working behaviour with `.ft0{font: Arial 14px;line-height: 16px;}` or whatever other font type specified.